# interpret UDP data in Qt (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, udp

I am trying to receive Project cars UDP broadcast,

I am able to receive data (cf: the code just under) but it is un readable and all "melted" in 1 long phrase.

```
//widget.cpp
 connect(mSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, [&](){
        if(mSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()){
            QByteArray datagram;
            datagram.resize(mSocket->pendingDatagramSize());


            mSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(),datagram.size());


            QDataStream in(&datagram, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
            in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_11);
            in >>altitude>>temperature>>humidity;

            QString textAlt = QString::number(altitude);
            QString textTemp = QString::number(temperature);
            QString textHum= QString::number(humidity);

            ui->lineEdit->setText(tr("%1 °C").arg(altitude));
            ui->lineEdit_2->setText(textTemp);
            ui->lineEdit_3->setText(textHum);

        }
    });
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_connectButton_clicked()
{
    mSocket->bind(ui->port->value(),QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
}
```

here is my try to interpret the data (only the first 9 byts frome the byteArray : expl: sWorldPosition[3]...).

```
//receiver.cpp
Receiver::Receiver(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

    struct sParticipantInfo
    {
        int sWorldPosition[3]; // 0
        int sCurrentLapDistance; // 6
        int sRacePosition; // 8
        int sLapsCompleted; // 9
        int sCurrentLap; // 10
        int sSector; // 11
        float sLastSectorTime; // 14
    };


    statusLabel = new QLabel(tr("Listening for broadcasted messages"));
    statusLabel->setWordWrap(true);

    quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Quit"));

    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(45454, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);

    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));
    connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

    QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    buttonLayout->addStretch(1);
    buttonLayout->addWidget(quitButton);
    buttonLayout->addStretch(1);

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(statusLabel);
    mainLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Broadcast Receiver"));
}

void Receiver::processPendingDatagrams()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
       struct sParticipantInfo* updPacket = reinterpret_cast<sParticipantInfo*>(datagram.data());



        qDebug() << "sWorldPosition[1]: " << updPacket->sWorldPosition[0];
         qDebug() << "sWorldPosition[2]: " << updPacket->sWorldPosition[1];
          qDebug() << "sWorldPosition[3]: " << updPacket->sWorldPosition[2];
        qDebug() << "sCurrentLapDistance: " << updPacket->sCurrentLapDistance;
        qDebug() << "sRacePosition " << updPacket->sRacePosition;
        qDebug() << "sLapsCompleted " << updPacket->sLapsCompleted;
        qDebug() << "sCurrentLap " << updPacket->sCurrentLap;
        qDebug() << "sSector " << updPacket->sSector;
        qDebug() << "sLastSectorTime" << updPacket->sLastSectorTime;
    }
}
```

but i am spotting some errors in the last lines the for exemple the arrows in: updPacket->sLastSectorTime...

## So I would have two questions:

1. Am i using well the "struct" type to parce data?
2. And is it good to use "reinterpret_cast" / am I using it well?

Comment: _"is it good to use "reinterpret_cast""_ That's rarely good.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is invoking godly powers that allow you the programmer to tell the compiler, "No matter how stupid this looks, it'll work. Trust me." If you're wrong and it doesn't work... Well, you are out of luck. In this case, the sneder and receiver may disagree on the size of an `int`, the endian, and the padding required to maintain optimal alignment. Probably a couple other things I'm missing in there. In addition, the data buffer you are being given and about to cast may not be properly aligned for the data you are going to read after casting. Things can go very wrong, so be careful

Comment: C++ guarantees you can cast to a byte array, but makes no guarantees that the reverse is true. Some of this can be hand-waved away by ensuring that both sides have the identical or similar-enough systems, but you are still marching into grey areas that can work "Most of the time" or "Enough to make you think they work all of the time." Cross all your 't's, dot all the 'i's, and test the smurf out of things or read up on serialization.